# Cómo puedo mostrar los datos del usuario que ha iniciado sesion?

Tags: php, postgresql, session

Tratando de mostrar los datos del usuario que ha iniciado sesión, me encuentro con una problemática que no he podido resolver y es que quiero mostrar los datos del mismo, el código lo manejo de la siguiente manera:

`root/index.php` ... En este archivo tengo el formulario para captar el correo y la contraseña que están iniciando sesión

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$correo= filter_var($_POST['correo'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
 $errores = '';
if (empty($correo) or empty($contraseña)) {
    $errores .= '<li> Llena todos los campos </li>';
} else {
    try {
        $conexion = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=pruebaV user=postgres password=admin");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "ERROR:" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $statement = pg_prepare($conexion, "user_exist", "SELECT * FROM usuarios where correo = \$1  AND contraseña = \$2 ");
    $statement = pg_execute($conexion, "user_exist", array($correo,  $contraseña ));
    $resultado = pg_fetch_assoc($statement);
    print_r($resultado);
    if ($resultado !== False ){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['correo'] = $correo; //editado
        $buser= pg_prepare($conexion, "tipo_user", "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = \$1 ");
        $buser = pg_execute($conexion, "tipo_user", array($correo));
        $result2 = pg_num_rows($buser);
        if($result2 == 1){
            while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($buser)){
                $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
                $_SESSION['tipo_id'] = $row['tipo_id'];
                $_SESSION['depe_user'] = $row['depe_user'];
            }
        }//termina edicion
        header("Location: ../administrador/inicio.php");
    }else{
        $errores.='<li> Datos incorrectos </li>';
    }
}}?>
```

A continuación lo mando a
root/templates/cabecera.php

````
``` <?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['correo'])) {
} else {
    header("Location: ../administrador/index.php");
}
?>```
````

Por último hago un include de la cabecera en la página de inicio
root/inicio.php

`<?php include("../administrador/templates/cabecera.php"); ?>`

aquí mismo hago un llamado de la $_session['correo']

```
<div class="alert alert-success col-md-12" role="alert">
    <h4 class="alert-heading">Bienvenido:</h4>
    <p><?php echo $_SESSION['nombre']; ?></p>
    <p class="mb-1"><?php echo $_SESSION['correo']; ?></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cual error es el que te sale???

Comment: bueno, lo que quiero conseguir es que aparezcan los datos del usuario logueado en el root/inicio.php

`<div class="alert alert-success col-md-12" role="alert">
    <h4 class="alert-heading">Bienvenido:</h4>
    <p><?php echo $_SESSION['nombre'] ?></p>
    <p class="mb-1"><?php echo $_SESSION['correo']; ?></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">`

Warning: Undefined array key "nombre" in C:\xampp\htdocs\dpacontratos\administrador\inicio.php on line 5

Comment: pero el error que me comentas no esta en tus post ... y el codigo que compartes en ningun lado creas el nodo del array $_SESSION['nombre'] ... ni le asignas el valor pasado por $_POST ..... lo que quiero que comprendas es que te falta código por desarrollar/escribir ...

Comment: traté de hacerlo de la manera en que se muestra la edicion, quizá ahora se vea lo que trato de hacer

Comment: ok vamos por partes tienes que hacer debug antes que te salgas del archivo index.php al fina ponele un var_dump($_SESSION) para comprobar que guardaste ...

Comment: según el error, no estas llegando a guardar el nombre ... osea que no se crea $_SESSION['nombre']

Comment: En el index haces `session_start()`? No se ve que lo hagas y es la primera cosa que debes hacer siempre que quieras usar la sesión (ten cuidado si incluyes otros scripts, etc). Sin eso, afectar el array $_SESSION no tiene efecto

Comment: @Alfabravo lo tiene en /cabecera.php

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 no es evidente que esté incluyendo. Dice que lo está enviando pero no sé si eso significa usar header o qué es

Comment: bueno hay que esperar que comente ... yo igual le entendi mas o menos ...

Comment: En el index hago el `session_start()` después del try-catch... y es correcno, no los guarda, después de hacer el `var_dump($_SESSION)` me arroja lo siguiente:

array(1) { ["correo"]=> string(17) "correo@correo.com" }

Esto lo tuve que imprimir en inicio.php... ahora sé que la información que está en el  $buser del index es correcto, porque si se levanta el servicio, arroja error en el while, pero muestra lo que se mando a llamar en el query, simplemente no lo guarda (ya corregí el codigo)

Comment: Solucionado chicos!... recargué la página tal cual está el código y ya me guarda los valores, editaré la publicación para quien le sirva... muchas gracias por su apoyo